# Foundation 6: How to set .is-open-right translateX value with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, zurb-foundation, css-transforms, off-canvas-menu

I am building a website with Foundation 6 using CSS instead of SCSS. I'm using the responsive off-canvas drill-down menu on small screens, and by default, the off-canvas menu width is 250px.

**Problem: I would like this to be the full width of the browser window instead.**

### Setting the Width

I have used JavaScript to dynamically set the `.off-canvas.position-right` `width` to the width of the window, and `right` to the negative width of the window. I've also set the `.off-canvas .drilldown` `max-width` to the width of the window.

This works well, and here's how I did it:

```
function setOffCanvasWidth() {

    var windowWidth = window.innerWidth,
        offCanvasRight = document.querySelector( '.off-canvas.position-right' ),
        isDrilldown = document.querySelector( '.off-canvas .is-drilldown' );

    offCanvasRight.style.width = windowWidth + "px";
    offCanvasRight.style.right = "-" + windowWidth + "px";
    isDrilldown.style.maxWidth = windowWidth + "px";

}
setOffCanvasWidth();
```

I'm happy with this part, but it only solves half of the problem.

### Moving the Off-Canvas

In addition to dealing with the width of the menu, `.is-open-right` is moving everything over by -250px using `transform: translateX()`.

I tried including these lines in my function to set the `transform: translateX()` value to the negative width of the window:

```
var offCanvasWrapperInner = document.querySelector( '.off-canvas-wrapper-inner.is-off-canvas-open.is-open-right' );
offCanvasWrapperInner.style.transform = "translateX(-" + windowWidth + "px)";
```

But this didn't work. I think it has to do with the fact that `.off-canvas-wrapper-inner` doesn't have the class `.is-open-right` when the window loads. That class is added dynamically after clicking the hamburger toggle button, which has a class of `.menu-icon`. So I tried adding a `click` event listener, but it still doesn't work.

Here is my JS code in its entirety:

```
function setOffCanvasWidth() {

    var windowWidth = window.innerWidth,
            offCanvasRight = document.querySelector( '.off-canvas.position-right' ),
            isDrilldown = document.querySelector( '.off-canvas .is-drilldown' ),
            menuIcon = docuemnt.querySelector( '.menu-icon' ),
            offCanvasWrapperInner = document.querySelector( '.off-canvas-wrapper-inner.is-off-canvas-open.is-open-right' );

    offCanvasRight.style.width = windowWidth + "px";
    offCanvasRight.style.right = "-" + windowWidth + "px";
    isDrilldown.style.maxWidth = windowWidth + "px";

    menuIcon.addEventListener( 'click', function() {
        offCanvasWrapperInner.style.transform = "translateX(-" + windowWidth + "px)";
    } );

}
setOffCanvasWidth();
```

### Where Am I Going Wrong?

I'm not looking for anyone to code the solution for me, necessarily, but any feedback and direction on how I might set the `.is-open-right` `translateX` value would be very helpful.

Here is the entire project code: https://github.com/paulshryock/paulshryock/releases/tag/v0.0.1
Here is a live demo: https://paulshryock.github.io/paulshryock/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `translateX` value of `-100%`. Percentage transformations are based on the element's dimensions, so `100%` would be equal the element's width. At this point no JavaScript would be needed.

On that note, I would recommend setting the menu's `left` to `100%` instead of setting `right` to the negative width.

Comment: You're right, it was a purely CSS solution for the .is-open-right transform: translateX value. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help! -